# How to call my library function in codeigniter?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter-3

I have created a library and a function defined for trim and show half character:

```
class Strlen_trim {
function trim_text($input, $length, $ellipses = true, $strip_html = true) {
    //strip tags, if desired
    if ($strip_html) {
        $input = strip_tags($input);
    }

    //no need to trim, already shorter than trim length
    if (strlen($input) <= $length) {
        return $input;
    }

    //find last space within length
    $last_space = strrpos(substr($input, 0, $length), ' ');
    $trimmed_text = substr($input, 0, $last_space);

    //add ellipses (...)
    if ($ellipses) {
        $trimmed_text .= '...';
    }

    return $trimmed_text;
  }
 }
```

controller side

```
$this->load->library('Strlen_trim');
$this->Strlen_trim->trim_text();
```

view side

```
<?php echo trim_text($widgets['content'],15); ?>
```

Comment: what error you are getting.

Comment: i am getting this errror  Call to undefined function trim_text() from view side

Comment: to call function in view use $this->libraryname->functioname(ardguments);

Comment: i tried this $this->Strlen_trim->trim_text($widgets['content'],15); in view side

Comment: @vivekanandgangesh , i would suggest instead of using custom library , use CI text helper for this

Comment: use small s not capital. $this->strlen_trim->trim_text($widgets['content'],15);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On view side your calling function directly that is the error.

You can do it like this.

> **Way 1:**
>
> Controller Side:
>
> ```
>  $this->load->library('Strlen_trim');
>  $data = array(); 
>  $data['widget_content'] = $this->Strlen_trim->trim_text($widgets['content'],15);
>  $this->load->view('view_name',$data);
> ```
>
> View Side:
>
> `<?php echo  $widget_content; ?>`
>
> **Way 2:**
>
> Controller Side:
>
> ```
> $this->load->library('Strlen_trim');
> ```
>
> View Side:
>
> `<?php echo $this->Strlen_trim->trim_text($widgets['content'],15); ?>`

Answer (score 0):

***I would suggest use CI inbuilt `text` helper instead of creating custom library for that ,***

Load `text` helper in your `autoload.php` like this :

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('text');
```

In your view use `character_limiter` or `word_limiter`, whatever u want like this:

```
// with character_limiter()
<?php echo character_limiter($widgets['content'],15); ?>

// with word_limiter()
<?php echo word_limiter($widgets['content'],5); ?>
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/text_helper.html#word_limiter

Comment: did u check my answer is it helpful